# xUnit MessageSink for Collection Fixture does not generate output

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit, xunit.net

I'm trying to add diagnostic output to my xUnit tests. For this, I'm using a combination of *Collection Fixture* and `IMessageSink`. This is my code:

```cs
using System;
using Xunit;
using Xunit.Abstractions;
using Xunit.Sdk;

namespace MessageSink
{
    [Collection("My collection")]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        private readonly MyCollectionFixture _fixture;

        public UnitTest1(MyCollectionFixture fixture)
        {
            _fixture = fixture;
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            _fixture.Sink.OnMessage(new DiagnosticMessage("Hello World"));
        }
    }

    public class MyCollectionFixture : IDisposable
    {
        public MyCollectionFixture(IMessageSink sink)
        {
            Sink = sink;
        }

        public IMessageSink Sink { get; }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }

    [CollectionDefinition("My collection")]
    public class MyCollection : ICollectionFixture<MyCollectionFixture>
    {
    }
}
```

Within the test project, I've created the following `xunit.runner.json`:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://xunit.net/schema/current/xunit.runner.schema.json",
  "diagnosticMessages": true
}
```

And this is my project configuration:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.9.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.3">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.0.2">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="xunit.runner.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I'd expect *Hello World* within the output of the test runner - but it is empty.

I (hopefully ) followed the docs in the correct way:

- [Shared Context between Tests](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context#collection-fixture)
- [Capturing Output](https://xunit.net/docs/capturing-output)
- [Configuration Files](https://xunit.net/docs/configuration-files)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks and cheers

Comment: Did you ever get this working with `IMessageSink`?  I tried it too and even following their instructions the way that you did, it did not send any output for me either.  I am unable to use `ITestOutputHelper` because I need to redirect output at the time that the Collection Fixture is created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I learned [here](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/discussions/2387), it is not possible. `IMessageSink` does not log into the test runner's UI output - only into the log file.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to come back to answer.  I did at least get it going to the log file (by which I assume you mean Visual Studio's "Output" window with the "Test" category selected".  But sadly no, as you said, not in the main output itself.  I'm actually of the opinion that the old school gtest tests we had were better in this regard.  I preferred having the output all mixed together.

Comment: I couldn't agree more

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to extend `IClassFixture<MyCollectionFixture>` to get that working for diagnostic messages.

For in-test messages, try using `ITestOutputHelper` which you can pass in into your test class along with `MyCollectionFixture`.

Check docs out: https://xunit.net/docs/capturing-output